# Import Customer Address

Tags: magento-1.7, customer, dataflow

Magento's default customer import doesn't import customer address.All other info except address is getting imported.

CSV header,

```
website email,group_id,prefix,firstname,middlename,lastname,suffix,password_hash,taxvat,billing_prefix,billing_firstname,billing_middlename,billing_lastname,   billing_suffix,billing_street1,billing_city,billing_region,billing_country_id,billing_postcode, billing_telephone,shipping_prefix,shipping_firstname,shipping_middlename,shipping_lastname,shipping_suffix,shipping_street1,shipping_city,shipping_region,shipping_country  shipping_postcode,shipping_telephone,shipping_company,shipping_fax,created_in,is_subscribed,group
```

Values,

```
base,someemail@msn.com,4,first,last,f7dcc0067542778c9444fsd68d5b369:kJ,none,mr,first,last,"22 some address",somecity,Australian Capital Territory,AUS,1111,123455,first,last,"22 some address",somecity,Australian Capital Territory,1111,123455,Default Store View,point sale
```

Are there any other ways available to import customers

Answer (score 4):

For people using a Dataflow Profile to import customer addresses, don't forget to add the country code (`billing_country` or `shipping_country`) and a post code (`billing_postcode` or `shipping_postcode`). Without those values, the address will not be taken into account.

If the address still doesn't show up, add those lines of code at the end of the `__construct` function in `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Convert/Adapter/Customer.php`:

```
Mage::log($this->_billingRequiredFields);
Mage::log($this->_shippingRequiredFields);
```

Run the profile and check your `system.log` in the `var/log/` folder. You'll get a list of all required fields you'll need to fill in for the address to be saved.

Answer (score 3):

I just did this a few days back. Using the standard Import/Export functionality, there doesn't seem to be problem importing addresses. The main difference seems to be underscore prefixing most address related field names (and suffixing some).

The easiest way is to do standard Export (instead of running a Dataflow profile) and see what the header looks like. Anyway, this is my CSV header fields:

```
email
_website
_store
confirmation
created_at
created_in
disable_auto_group_change
dob
firstname
gender
group_id
lastname
middlename
password_hash
prefix
rp_token
rp_token_created_at
store_id
suffix
taxvat
website_id
password
_address_city
_address_company
_address_country_id
_address_fax
_address_firstname
_address_lastname
_address_middlename
_address_postcode
_address_prefix
_address_region
_address_street
_address_suffix
_address_telephone
_address_vat_id
_address_default_billing_
_address_default_shipping_
```